# Merge two columns while display in yii2 table widget

Tags: yii, yii2, widget

My code using yii to display table is

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    'HRMS_candidateFirstName',
                    'HRMS_candidateLastName',
                     'HRMS_candidaterRefType',
                     'HRMS_candidateStatus',
                   ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                ],
            ]);
```

It prints First name and last name as different col. Like this [image]

I want it like this

[image]

I searched in documentation but not able to find.

How to do this?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/51306-merge-two-or-more-columns-in-gridview/       hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must build a calculated column

here you can find a very good [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/) 
Essentially you must add to your model a function for `calculate` the column like this

**In Model**

```
/* Getter for person full name */
public function getFullName() {
   return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}

/* Your model attribute labels */
public function attributeLabels() {
   return [
       /* Your other attribute labels */
       'fullName' => Yii::t('app', 'Full Name')
   ];
}
```

and the in **view**

```
echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      'id',
      'fullName',
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ]
]);
```

If you don't need filer and sortig this is all otherwise you can find wath you need in the tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

It can be done directly in view file like this-

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'an_attributeid',
            'label' => 'yourLabel',
            'value' => function($model) { return $model->first_name  . " " . $model->last_name ;},
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',],
    ],
]);?>
```